# ESModules [object Module] How do I create an instance of the module?

Tags: javascript

I have question about JavaScript ESModules.

```
import project from './project.js';
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(project));
// [object Object]
```

```
import * as project from './project.js';
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(project));
// [object Module]
```

Sample Project

https://github.com/standard-software/parts-Node_Deno_ProjectTemplate/blob/v1.2.0/Backup/project04/test/test_source_3.js

I want to do clone or cloneDeep Module.

I am making library Parts.js
include clone / cloneDeep.
use cloneFunction.cloneObject

https://github.com/standard-software/partsjs/blob/v6.3.0/source/root/clone.js#L46

```
const projectClone = clone(project);
// isObject(project) === true -> no problem
// isModule(project) === true -> problem. I cant do clone.
```

property copy is no problem.
I can't do create new instace Module(object like).

```
const projectClone = new Module() // this is error.
```

How to do create new instance Module ?

Comment: Could you please provide the exact error message?

Comment: Where have you previously defined the `Module` object?

Comment: You can write a file (with `fs`) and import the file and there you have a new instance of `Module`

Comment: I want to do clone [object Module]

error message

`const cloneProject = new Module();`
`error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Module is not defined
const cloneProject = new Module();`

Answer (score 1):

Should it be as follows? You need to define `Module` as part of the import statement.

```
import * as Module from './project.js';
const projectClone = new Module();
```

Or, conversely:

```
import * as Project from './project.js';
const projectClone = new Project();
```

Related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#Creating_a_module_object

Comment: Not working properly

`import * as project from '../source/index.js';
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(project));
const cloneProject = new project();
console.log(project.test(), project.test1());`

`[object Module]
error: Uncaught TypeError: project is not a constructor
const cloneProject = new project();`

Comment: Is what you're importing a class or other constructable object?

Comment: If you like it, I would like you to ask the question again including the link destination.

A clone of Object([object Object]) is fine. Create an instance and copy the properties. it's simple. It has been realized.

I'm having a problem with a clone of Module([object Module]).

Module([object Module]) has no constructor.

I don't know how to create another instance of Module([object Module]).